# Python Editing lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a little program to edit lines of text in a text file.

I'm continually getting errors.

**My code:**

```
def Main():

    myfile = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you wish to edit: ")
    change = input("please enter the line number you wish to change: ")
    newLine = raw_input("please enter the new text: ")

    f = open(myfile, 'r')
    content = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    f = open(myfile, 'w')
    content[change-1] = newLine + '\n'
    f.writelines(content)

    #the for loop is just for checking it worked!!
    for things in content:
        print things

    f.close()
```

**My errors:**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):

    File "/home/hippopotamus/Desktop/Server and Client Project/Client/Edit.py", line 21, in <module>

    Main()

    File "/home/hippopotamus/Desktop/Server and Client Project/Client/Edit.py", line 11, in Main

    content[change-1] = newLine + '\n'
    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: @KenWhite Dw, added the tag after your comment. :-)

Comment: @Tropic Hippo Please upload the file you are working with.

Comment: thanks for the edit I'm still new and learning how to contribute and ask questions correctly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a try except so that your code looks like the following:

```
myfile = raw_input("Please enter the name of the file you wish to edit: ")
change = input("please enter the line number you wish to change: ")
newLine = raw_input("please enter the new text: ")

f = open(myfile, 'r')
content = f.readlines()
f.close()

try:
  content[change-1] = newLine + '\n'
  f = open(myfile, 'w')
  f.writelines(content)
  f.close()
except IndexError:
  print "Specified line number out of range"

#the for loop is just for checking it worked!!
for things in content:
    print things
```

Of course, you could improve this further by checking for successful opening of the file.

If this doesn't solve (or at least indicate) your problem, ensure that the file you are working with has the correct line breaks and they are where they are expected to be.

Comment: hey man your welcome thanks so much for your help, I'm still very new and learning and its hard to know where to get good help.